# Python if-statement based on content of HTML title tag

Tags: python

We are trying to write a Python script to parse HTML with the following conditions:

1. If the HTML title tag contains the string "Record doesn't exist," then continue running a loop.
2. If NOT, download the page contents.

How do we write an if-statement based on the conditions?

We're aware of Beautiful Soup, unfortunately we don't have permission to install it on the machine we're using.

Our code:

```
    import urllib2
    opp1 = 1
    oppn = 2

    for opp in range(opp1, oppn + 1):
        oppurl = (something.com)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(oppurl)
        html = response.read()

    # syntax error on the next line # 

    if Title == 'Record doesn't exist':
        continue

    else:
        oppfilename = 'work/opptest' + str(opp) + '.htm'
        oppfile = open(oppfilename, 'w')
        opp.write(opphtml)
        print 'Wrote ', oppfile
        votefile.close()
```

Comment: Well, the code as posted should raise a `NameError`, as you have used the variable `Title` without defining it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: You don't need to "install" Beautiful Soup, go here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/3.2/view/head:/BeautifulSoup.py click download, put it in a text file.  You are allowed to save text files on the machine you're using, are you not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the contents of the title tag:

```
m = re.search('<title>(.*?)</title>', html)
if m:
    title = m.group(1)
```

Comment: @ironchefpython: TONY THE PONY, HE COMES! (To be fair, reading one single tag is a different proposition to actually parsing HTML with regex.)

Comment: Best not to teach the younglings bad habits, it will only make them easier to turn to the dark side.

Comment: @ironchefpython: Right, I'll be more careful from now on. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  It's an amazingly easy to use library for parsing HTML documents and fragments.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for opp in range(opp1,oppn+1):
    oppurl =  (www.myhomepage.com)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(oppurl)
    html = response.read()


    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    if soup.head.title == "Record doesn't exist":
            continue
        else:
            oppfilename = 'work/opptest'+str(opp)+'.htm'
            oppfile = open(oppfilename,'w')
            opp.write(opphtml)
            print 'Wrote ',oppfile
            votefile.close()
```

---- EDIT ----

If Beautiful Soup isn't an option, I personally would resort to a regular expression.  However, I refuse to admit that in public, as I won't let allow people to know I would stoop to the easy solution.  Let's see what's in that "batteries included" bag of tricks.

[`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) looks promising, let's see if we can bent it to our will.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def titleFinder(html):
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            self.intitle = tag == "title"
        def handle_data(self, data):
            if self.intitle:
                self.title = data

    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.title

>>> print titleFinder('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
                '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
Test
```

That's incredibly painful.  That almost as wordy as Java.  (just kidding)

What else is there? There's [`xml.dom.minidom`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) A "Lightweight DOM implementation".  I like the sound of "lightweight", means we can do it with one line of code, right?

```
import xml.dom.minidom
html = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>'

title = ''.join(node.data for node in xml.dom.minidom.parseString(html).getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE)

>>> print title
Test
```

### And we have our one-liner!

---

So I heard that these regular expressions things are pretty efficient as extracting bits of text from HTML.  I think you should use those.