# AttributeError: XX instance has no attribute 'intitle'

Tags: python, html-parsing

The code is from:
[Python if-statement based on content of HTML title tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335836/python-if-statement-based-on-content-of-html-title-tag)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def titleFinder(html):
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            self.intitle = tag == "title"
        def handle_data(self, data):
            if self.intitle:
                self.title = data

    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.title

>>> print titleFinder('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
                '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
Test
```

However, I got the following error message when the code below is run,

**AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'intitle'**

How can i fix the error message? Any ideas?

Code:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2

def titleFinder(html):
    intitle = False
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            self.intitle = tag == "title"
        def handle_data(self, data):
            if self.intitle:
                self.title = data

    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.title

response=urllib2.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680074/attributeerror-xx-instance-has-no-attribute-intitle")
html= response.read()
print titleFinder(html)
```

The trackback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\labs\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print titleFinder(html)
  File "D:\labs\test.py", line 14, in titleFinder
    parser.feed(html)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 142, in goahead
    if i < j: self.handle_data(rawdata[i:j])
  File "D:\labs\test.py", line 10, in handle_data
    if self.intitle:
AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'intitle'
```

**[UPDATE]**

I finally solved the problem! Thank you, Martijn Pieters!

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2

def titleFinder(html):
    class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self):
            HTMLParser.__init__(self)
            self.title = ''
            self.intitle = False  #!!!
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            self.intitle = tag == "title"
        def handle_data(self, data):
            if self.intitle:
                self.title = self.title+data #!!!

    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    return parser.title

response=urllib2.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680074/attributeerror-xx-instance-has-no-attribute-intitle")

html= response.read()
print titleFinder(html)
```

Comment: When reporting errors in python, please include the *full* traceback, so we don't have to guess quite as much where your error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handle_data` method is called before `handle_starttag` has been called, and there is no `intitle` attribute set at that moment.

Simply add `intitle = False` to your class:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    intitle = False

    # your methods
```

`handle_data` is called for *all* text nodes in your document, including whitespace, so it's not that unusual for it to be called before `handle_starttag`.

Comment: After adding "intitle = False", I still got the same error message.

Comment: @MattElson: Then please include the *full* traceback. The code you show has only *one* location that refers to `self.intitle`, and my answer should solve that case, but a full traceback might reveal another location you forgot about.